# Vue, access component methods

Tags: vue.js

I have an issue when trying to access component functions from within the config of plugins. For example, I would like to use vue-flatpickr as so:

```
  mounted() {
    this.flatpicker = flatpickr(this.$refs.dateInput, {
      onChange(date) {
        this.$emit("dateChanged", date);
      }
    });
  }
```

However, I get an error

> Uncaught TypeError: this.$emit is not a function

The problem is not only with emit but also with any function defined in the methods section as *this* points to the instance of the plugin. I realize this might not be an adequate approach, I am open to any suggestions!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried this:

```
  mounted() {
    var self = this;
    this.flatpicker = flatpickr(self.$refs.dateInput, {
      onChange(date) {
        self.$emit("dateChanged", date);
      }
    });
  }
```